# Add shadow to html element

Tags: css

I need to create an element with shadow like in the mockup: 
http://take.ms/UdLFk
But I created only 
http://take.ms/lns0J .
I have next styles:

```
    .shadow {
        width: 45px;
        left: 37px;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
```

My markup:

```
<div  class=" shadow"></div>
```

So, how i can get a shadow like in mockup? I searched many articles but they did not help me.

Comment: I see you know how it is done, so why not play a little bit more until you get it like in the mockups. No one can adjust it perfectly for you!

Comment: I played with it, but i didnt get it like in the mockups

Comment: Why not add it directly to the image if you need a shadow on it?

Comment: @Pete You have alot more control over CSS shadows. This could be an advantage if you want to make for instance a hover effect where the shadow changes.

Comment: @Maharkus just use an svg then, then you can use a drop shadow and have even more control over it than a box shadow

Comment: CSS shadows are much simpler to make. You don't need to make a shadow, export it, put it into the code. CSS shadows are just a boxes you can animate using transitions. SVG is good and very handy, don't get me wrong, but using SVG for everything just seems to be quite the overkill imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `border-radius` (with a small `height` and a `background-color` that fits the shadow) to the element will give the shadow a nice rounded effect. Maybe decrease the opacity a little and you'll get pretty close. Also try using `z-index: -1` to put the shadow behind the image.

```css
.shadow {
  width: 45px;
  left: 37px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
  <div class="shadow"></div>
```